# La fecha se muestra de manera incorrecta en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Estoy usando Laravel 6, y deseo obtener el siguiente formato de fecha:

Ejemplo: **Lunes, 10 de Enero del 2020**

Para lo cual apliqué el siguiente código:

Nota: No estoy utilizando Carbon, porque no se si usando eso podría obtener el resultado que estoy buscando.

```
$fecha = date('Y-m-d');
 
$numero_dia = date('d', strtotime($fecha));
$dia = date('l', strtotime($fecha));
$mes = date('F', strtotime($fecha));
$anio = date('Y', strtotime($fecha));

$dias_ES = array("Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado", "Domingo");
$dias_EN = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
$nombredia = str_replace($dias_EN, $dias_ES, $dia);
$meses_ES = array("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre");
$meses_EN = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
$nombreMes = str_replace($meses_EN, $meses_ES, $mes);


$registro -> fecha = $nombredia.", ".$numero_dia." de ".$nombreMes." del ".$anio; //Guardo en mi base de datos
```

Pero el resultado que me arroja es el siguiente:

**2020-02-10**

Answer (score 5):

Configuración

Lo primero que debes hacer es entrar al archivo `app.php` que se localiza en:

```
tuproyecto
    config
        app.php
```

Donde vas a buscar la clave siguiente y cambiar su valor de `en` a `es` para que muestre el resultado en español.

```
'locale' => 'es',
```

Posterior no necesitas hacer todo ese código para obtener la fecha con el formato deseado considerando que Laravel ya incluye Carbon como biblioteca para gestionar el manejo de tiempos y fechas, alcanza con que hagas lo siguiente:

```
    $fecha  = now();
    $mes    = $fecha->monthName;
    $anio   = $fecha->year;
    $dia    = $fecha->dayName;
    $diaNumero = $fecha->day;
    return $dia." ".$diaNumero." de ".$mes." de ".$anio;
```

- Con la primer variable obtenemos un formato general de fecha
- Con la propiedad `monthName` obtenemos el nombre del mes que recuperamos en la línea anterior
- Con la propiedad `year` recuperamos solo el año
- Con la propiedad `dayName` obtenemos el nombre del día de la fecha actualmente recuperada
- Con la propiedad `day` obtenemos el número de día

Finalmente concatenas todas esas variables y tendrías una salida así:

> domingo 9 de febrero de 2020